# Get Configuration Property class bean in SpringBoot Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have a class defined to auutomatically load properties from applicaton-*.properties in my sprintboot applicatoin:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my-app")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class MyAppProperties {

  private String propertyX;
  private String propertyY;

..

}
```

Now here is my Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class MessageProcessorApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private static RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public static MyAppProperties myAppProperties;

  @Test
  public void testSomething(){
     doSomeSeetup(myAppProperties.getPropertyX()) //myAppProperties is null!! why?
}
```

In my test, the myAppProperties is always null. How do i get instance of this in my test??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate `MessageProcessorApplicationTests` with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to auto load application.properties file

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class MessageProcessorApplicationTests {

@Autowired
  private static RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public static MyAppProperties myAppProperties;

  @Test
  public void testSomething(){
     doSomeSeetup(myAppProperties.getPropertyX());

}
```

Comment: if you use JUnit Platform (Junit5) `SpringBootTests` includes `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` which makes adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` unnecessary

Comment: I am just  using  the standard springboot web flux starter and the spring boot starter test. How do I know if its using junit 4 or 5?

Comment: Use command `mvn dependency:tree | grep junit` to check junit version

Answer (score 0):

Add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyAppProperties.class)` to your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyAppProperties.class)
public class MessageProcessorApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public MyAppProperties myAppProperties;

  @Test
  public void testSomething(){
     doSomeSeetup(myAppProperties.getPropertyX()) //myAppProperties is null!! why?
}
```

Comment: This did not work.
The myAppProperties was still null in the \@Test and the \@BeforeClass methods.

I added the RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation to the class and it worked. Is this the right way?

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) is used to provide a bridge between Spring Boot test features and JUnit. Whenever we are using any Spring Boot testing features in our JUnit tests, this annotation will be required.